# strange "" quotes in html before asp.net control

Tags: asp.net, html, custom-controls

i'm seeing a really strange issue with asp.net rendering. i have EXACTLY this in the relevant part of the .aspx (just replaced names of paths and controls):

```
<div id="header">
 <% if (SiteSettings.SiteName.Equals("sx") || SiteSettings.SiteName.Equals("sw"))
    { %>
        <sc:sublayout runat="server" renderingid="{B04CFA1A-6B5B-49D3-8000-339DBE9899C1}"
          path="/layouts/AX/HeaderSublayout.ascx" id="AXHeader" placeholder="content"></sc:sublayout>
 <% }
    else
    { %><!-- bla1 --><ax:strangeBehavingControl id="HeaderInclude" runat="server" IncludeType="Header" /><!-- bla2 -->
 <% } %>
</div>
```

the rendered html looks like:

```
<!-- bla1 -->
""
expected content from strangeBehavingControl
<!-- bla2 -->
```

the .ascx for strangeBehavingControl is really simple:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="strangeBehavingControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="layouts.strangeBehavingControl" %>
```

no extra spaces anywhere, checked already many times. the code behind is also really simple:

```
public partial class strangeBehavingControl: System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            var filePath = GetFilePath();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath) && File.Exists(Server.MapPath(filePath)))
                Response.WriteFile(filePath);
        }  
    }
```

so i was thinking that the strange "" where inside the rendered included files, but i checked them manually and they start with the expected characters. any idea how can those characters being inserted there?

Comment: "Basically i have something like this in the .aspx:" <-- can you upload exactly what you have in the .aspx (it could be just a typo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are generating markup for your control incorrectly.  Your render method should be using the `HtmlTextWriter` instance given to it, and *not* using any direct output writing method on `Response`.

It also looks like a rather strange setup, as you are writing out the contents as a `UserControl`, meaning it will be rendered within a page.  Is it correct to assume you are always outputting either valid HTML or plain text?

I would suggest you change your `Render` method as follows:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    var filePath = GetFilePath();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath) && File.Exists(Server.MapPath(filePath)))
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
            writer.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Comment: going to try this first in the morning, thanks! yes we are always outputting valid HTML headers, which are created by another team

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the control file has another charset.
Verify that your file does not have extra characters at the start, and if so remove them.
You may have to use a smart text editor that allows you to do that.

I had the same extra space problem, but my control was not implementing a `Render()` method.